# Difference between users listed under home directory and those not

Tags: centos, users

I see some of the users I can find under `/home` directory in centos but not rest of the users.

Users that are listed under `/home` directory, I can login as those users with command

```
su username
```

To find rest of the users, I had to use the command:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

To login as one of these rest of the users, I need to use command

```
sudo -u username
```

what is the difference?

Comment: Can you really log in as all those users with `sudo -u <username>`?

Comment: Not exactly login but could perform the actions limited to those users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a similar command to yours:

```
$ cut -d: -f1,6,7 /etc/passwd
root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
...
gareth:/home/gareth:/bin/bash
...
```

you will notice that the only accounts with a `/home` directory are the ones where a) the second column above has a path to a directory within `/home`, and b) have a shell in the third column (`/bin/bash`).

All the other users cannot log in as they either have a shell of `/sbin/nologin`, which as the name implies doesn't allow login, or have a shell that is a specific command, such as `/sbin/halt`.

You can run commands as the other users, or even run a shell:

```
$ sudo -u daemon whoami
daemon
$ sudo -u daemon bash
$ whoami
daemon
$ echo $HOME
/
```

but you won't have a home directory within `/home`.

More importantly, you can't log in at a login prompt or with `su` or `ssh` on these accounts because the shell is `/sbin/nologin` and their passwords will have been disabled (look for a `!!` or a `*` in the 2nd column of `sudo less /etc/shadow`).

These accounts are all *system* accounts used by services such as email or dhcp or used to shutdown the system.

You shouldn't really be running commands as these users using `sudo`.